# Using baposter class

Tags: miktex

So I'm trying to produce a poster using this baposter thing and I'm failing miserably at getting the thing to run. I have WinEdt and MiKTeX installed (I'm running Windows Vista) but when I try to `pdftexify` any of the example that comes in the folder you download I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 .
     ./../baposter.cls
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

And I don't understand why... the class file is in the folder that's being compiled so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Anyway, in my frustration I then reinstalled both MiKTeX and WinEdt, which only seems to have made things worse; when I try to compile old reports I've made  it tells me things such as:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `amsmath.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Which is weird as according to the MiKTeX Package Manager these packages are definitely installed, and in the past, whenever I've needed a new package, the thing has automatically installed.

So I guess my questions amount to: how have I managed to break this? and how do I get the `baposter` class working?

Sorry, I know I'm probably being very stupid, and there are probably very easy, obvious answers, but I'm really rather rubbish at computers and I can't get my head around this! :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Regarding the amsmath problem: Synchronize the repository in the package manager of miktex (menu "Repository). Do it in user + admin mode. Regarding baposter.cls: Don't you think it would be useful if you said where you got the class and which example you are actually trying to compile?

Comment: So the amsmath problem has now changed into a little pop up when I try to pdftexify that says:

Cannot run:

"C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\OFFICE11\WORDVIEW.EXE"
"C:\Users\John\Documents\Snowflakes\R..\Report.pdf"


Oh, and sorry, that probably would be useful! The class is from http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/ . I just downloaded baposter.tar.bz2 and the examples are all in there. And they all give the same error :/ .

Comment: And the location "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\OFFICE11\WORDVIEW.EXE" doesn't seem to exist on my computer either. There's a Cannot run: "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\OFFICE12\" instead but this has no WORDVIEW.EXE in it...

Comment: And this new problem seems only restricted to WinEdt - I can at least pdftexify these old reports using TeXworks now (hurray). Still having the same problem with the baposter class though.